# Loading images from a directory into an array with php

Tags: php, wordpress, image, dynamic, load

So I've killed an entire day trying to do something that would take someone who **actually** knows how to write php less than 2mins. Frustrating, but I learn by doing and trying to figure things out.

I'll feel like a failure for not getting this, but 8hrs and counting (yeah I know lame) is enough.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with this equation...

```
$dir = '../folder';

$images_array = glob($dir.'*.jpg');

$values['options'] = array( '<img src="$images_array"/>');
```

It's probably obvious, but all I need is for the images in mysite.com/folder to be loaded into the $values['options'] array.

If I simply state the path to a single image in  then the image is displayed (obviously because it's not reliant on anything else.)

Thanks.

@hellcode

Sorry about the mess in the 'comment' below your response. Unfortunately I couldn't get this to work? Maybe I need to provide more context.

The images in the folder are going to be used as checkbox items in a form. This was my original code (not working):

```
add_filter('frm_setup_new_fields_vars', 'frm_set_checked', 20, 2);
function frm_set_checked($values, $field){
  if($field->id == 187){
    $dir = '../folder';
    $images_array = glob($dir.'*.jpg');
    $values['options'] = array( '<img src="$images_array"/>');
    $values['use_key'] = true;
  }
  return $values;
}
```

I added your code like so:

```
add_filter('frm_setup_new_fields_vars', 'frm_set_checked', 20, 2);
function frm_set_checked($values, $field){
  if($field->id == 187){
    $dir = '../folder';
    $images_array = glob($dir.'*.jpg');
    $values['options'] = array();
    foreach($images_array as $image) {
      $values['options'][] = '<img src="'.$image.'"/>';
    }
    $values['use_key'] = true;
  }
  return $values;
}
```

But it didn't pull the files in unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$dir = '../folder';
$images_array = glob($dir.'*.jpg');
$values['options'] = array();
foreach($images_array as $image) {
  $values['options'][] = '<img src="'.$image.'"/>';
}
```

Comment: You don't have to add `$dir` in the img tag. In this case, `$image` already contains the path to the file

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I couldn't get this to work? Maybe I need to provide more context.

The images in the folder are going to be used as checkbox items in a form. This is the full code:

`add_filter('frm_setup_new_fields_vars', 'frm_set_checked', 20, 2);
function frm_set_checked($values, $field){
if($field->id == 187){

$dir = '../proofing';
$images_array = glob($dir.'*.jpg');
foreach($images_array as $image) {
  $values['options'] = array( '<img src="'.$image.'"/>');
$values['use_key'] = true;
}
}
return $values;
}`

Comment: @Bevels: the added code snippet is not enough to detect the error. It's important what the calling code will do with the returned array $values.

Comment: @Bevels: Are you using WordPress? Then you should add the tag to your question to get the experts for that.

Comment: Thanks @Hellcode - Yes I am using Wordpress. Sorry I didn't even think to mention it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, one problem may be that the `glob()` function uses the current directory, which can be anything, unless you use the `chdir()` function.

One thing that is definitely a problem is that you are using `glob()`'s return value, `$images_array`, as a string. Because it is an array that will not work.

Here is something that should work.

```
// Allowed image formats (also known as a "whitelist")
$allowedFormats = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'];

// Array for holding any found images
$foundImages = [];

// Get the real path from the relative path
$path = realpath('../folder');
if ($path === false) {
    die('The path does not exist!');
}
// Open a folder handle
$folder = dir($path);

// Read what is in the folder
while (($item = $folder->read()) !== false) {

    // .. is the parent folder, . is the current folder
    if ($item === '..' or $item === '.') {
        continue;
    }
    // Find the last dot in the filename
    // If it was not found then not image file
    $lastDot = strrpos($item, '.');
    if ($lastDot === false) {
        continue;
    }
    // Get the filetype and make sure it is
    // an allowed format
    $filetype = substr($item, $lastDot);
    if ( ! in_array($filetype, $allowedFormats)) {
        continue;
    }
    // Okay, looks like an image!
    $foundImages[] = $item;
}
// Close the folder handle
$folder->close();
```

Comment: I appreciate your response Sverri, unfortunately with my limited knowledge of PHP your answer is too far out of context to help me.